# CentOS 7 VMWare to Hyper-V migration - Disk not visible

Tags: centos7, hyper-v, windows-10

I had a VM which was migrated from VMWare, I've confirmed that the disk is as expected by booting to a Live CD, mounting, and inspecting the file system.

The system does also boot to a certain extent, but after a while it gives up trying, dropping to a 'dracut' terminal, I've read through the logs in `/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt` and saw this:

```
Hyper-V Virtual Machine detected, ATA device ignore set
```

In the terminal I also saw an error saying that `/dev/disk/by-uuid/{uuid here}` was not available. While I was in Ubuntu, I did check the UUIDs listed in the error, `/etc/fstab` and everything matched up with the output from `blkid`.

I've also done a clean install of CentOS, which booted normally, so it is almost certainly something about the migrated install.

Sorry if this doesn't give enough to go on, if anyone needs any specific information, I'll do my best to update the question with it.

In case it helps, I'm running Windows 10, version 1903, build 10.0.18941.1001 (which is the version Hyper-V reports being).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you will need to reconstruct the initramfs file `/boot/initramfs-(kernel version).img`, because of the virtual hardware change. The module used by CentOS kernel for virtual disk access is probably different. Please, follow these instructions:

- Attach a CentOS 7 installation ISO to the virtual machine
- Boot into Anaconda rescue mode ([instructions](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Rescue_Mode/#proc-booting-into-installer-rescue-mode)) ([alternative instructions](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-from-installation-dvdiso/))
- Make sure the filesystem inside the virtual disk is mounted correctly on `/mnt/sysimage`
- Use `dracut` to rebuild the initramfs: `# chroot /mnt/sysimage dracut --no-hostonly --force --regenerate-all --verbose`
- Program a SELinux relabelling: `# touch /mnt/sysimage/.autorelabel`
- Exit from Anaconda rescue mode

Initramfs is a filesystem image which the bootloader will extract to memory after loading the kernel and before switching execution context to it. Such image is expected to contain all modules the kernel will need to find the block device containing the root filesystem. I do not know what modules are needed for a Hyper-V virtual machine; if you are able to find them by yourself, you may tell `dracut` to add them to the rebuilt initramfs by using the `--add-drivers` argument.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue and the above command was not recognized. Is this ran from the dracut prompt?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by the default settings in ata_piix.
If a HyperV harddisk is detected the driver assumes that IDE is unnecessary and disables the port. To override this you can set the kernel parameter: `ata_piix.prefer_ms_hyperv=0`

Source: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/ata/ata_piix.c#L1572

After this the OS should boot up and you can rebuild your linux images to include the HyperV drivers.